# intellij navigate back shortcut not working

Tags: intellij-idea, ubuntu-16.04

I am using intellij 2017.3.2 and ubuntu 16.04 . I have a keyboard map shortcut in intellij for navigate back which is set to the default ctrl+alt+back arrow . Pressing these doesn't work. It does not do anything. When i would press it sometimes the a bar would pop up at the top of the gui for entering a command (for ubuntu) so I disabled this in ubunutu's keyboard shortcut menu. Still the navigate back does not work. Doing ctrl+windows-key+backarrow navigates somewhere- but not the standard intellij navigate back behavior. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to fix this?

Comment: Does the shortcut work when you set different key mapping for it?

Comment: yes- i made it ctrl+shift+left and it works with that

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that it is not a conflict with ubuntu shortcuts? 
Also, maybe this thread will help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/412046/unable-to-use-intellij-idea-keyboard-shortcuts-on-ubuntu

Comment: thanks that answers my question

Comment: Please accept my answer for future users if you find it helpful. Not all of us read comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a conflict with ubuntu shortcuts. See the thread on ["Ask ubuntu"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412046/unable-to-use-intellij-idea-keyboard-shortcuts-on-ubuntu) that may solve the issue.

Comment: I did everything they said and it still doesn't in work in intellij after disabling OS shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

Now IntelliJ has 'Default for GNOME' keymap with conflicted shortcuts remapped. 
Navigate back/forward is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow keys</kbd>

Comment: THey did not update their official keymap documentation however!